# Why PrintWriter does not works faster when I use ParallelFlux?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, io, project-reactor, printwriter

I'm discovering reactor library in Java and I run into `ParallelFlux<T> parallel()`.
I wanted to play around and created app which reads from file and rewrites it's content line by one to other files.

My file `file.txt` contains 1M lines of book titles.

The app:

```
package cdq.cdl.filereader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import cdq.cdl.utils.Utils;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("file.txt").getPath();
        HashMap<String, PrintWriter> printWriters = new HashMap<>();

        AtomicReference<Long> startMillis = new AtomicReference<>();
        AtomicReference<Long> endMillis = new AtomicReference<>();

        Flux.using(
                        () -> new FileReader(path),
                        fileReader -> Flux.fromStream(new BufferedReader(fileReader).lines()),
                        fileReader -> {
                            try
                            {
                                fileReader.close();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .doOnNext(line -> {
                    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    if (printWriters.containsKey(threadName)) {
                        printWriters.get(threadName).println(line);
                    } else {
                        FileWriter newFileWriter = null;
                        try
                        {
                            newFileWriter = new FileWriter(threadName + ".txt");
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        PrintWriter newPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(newFileWriter, true);
                        newPrintWriter.println(line);
                        printWriters.put(threadName, newPrintWriter);
                    }
                })
                .sequential()
                .doFirst(() -> {
                    printThreadName("doFirst");
                    startMillis.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
                })
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    printThreadName("doComplete");
                    endMillis.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
                })
                .doFinally(x -> {
                    printThreadName("doFinally");
                    printThreadName(String.valueOf(endMillis.get() - startMillis.get()));
                })
                .subscribe(Main::printThreadName);
    }

    private static void printThreadName(String message)
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t\t" + message);
    }
}
```

When I run this without

```
           .parallel()
           .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

it takes around 10000 milliseconds and I would expect that when I would use multiple threads (in my case 8) it would go multiple times faster, but in reality it's even slower. At the beginning I was writing to only one file so I assumed that PrintWriter locks file internally and threads has to wait for each other anyway and that's why I created map of writers, but it didn't help.

Is it possible that I/O operations can't be performed asynchronously and it doesn't matter that I write to multiple files?

This is example of console output on smaller dataset:

```
main        doFirst
parallel-5      For a Breath I Tarry
parallel-5      The Man Within
parallel-6      No Country for Old Men
parallel-6      Behold the Man
parallel-6      Oh! To be in England
parallel-6      The Wind's Twelve Quarters
parallel-6      Moab Is My Washpot
parallel-6      Number the Stars
parallel-6      When the Green Woods Laugh
parallel-6      His Dark Materials
parallel-6      Some Buried Caesar
parallel-6      Ego Dominus Tuus
parallel-6      Fame Is the Spur
parallel-6      I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings
parallel-6      The Golden Apples of the Sun
parallel-3      Postern of Fate
parallel-3      For a Breath I Tarry
parallel-3      No Highway
parallel-3      doComplete
parallel-3      doFinally
parallel-3      13
```

It does quite often happen that single thread consumes a lot of time in a row, but 1M data I could also find places where it was much more shuffled.

Comment: The disk isn’t multithreaded.